# Passing date range parameters to SQL/ActiveRecord query in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Here I have an Order and an OrderReport table. I am doing a join on it extracting some data from each of the tables.

```
 OrderReport.joins("INNER JOIN orders on orders.id = order_reports.for_object_id and order_reports.for_object_type = 'Order'").

group("order_reports.sales_user_id, EXTRACT(MONTH from event_at), orders.user_id,event_at").

pluck("order_reports.sales_user_id, EXTRACT(MONTH from event_at), orders.user_id,sum((cached_user_total_due - cached_sales_tax) * split_percentage), min(event_at)")
```

I have this very long sql + ActiveRecord query. I wanted to add an initializer and have it take in a date start and date end to make it a little more flexible for being able to pull reports from the previous year going forward.

The start and end date would be coming from the Order table which has an event_at column. I know I would start off by doing this:

```
  attr_reader :start_date, :end_date

  def initialize(start_date:, end_date:)
    @start_date = start_date
    @end_date = end_date 
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply achieve this by defining a scope like this:

```
class OrderReport < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :during, -> (start, end) {
    where('event_at >= ? AND event_at <=?', start, end)
  }
end
```

Then you can do your query super easy:

```
OrderReport.during(start_date, end_date).joins(pla pla pla)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a scope that utilizes the`ActiveRecord` interface using a range object in the following way:

```ruby
class OrderReport
  scope :for, -> (begins, ends) { where(event_at: begins..ends) }
end
```

You can use pass either `Date` objects or string arguments to it like:

```ruby
# with strings
OrderReport.for("2015-12-12", "2015-12-30")

# with date objects
begins = Date.new(2015, 12, 12)
ends   = Date.new(2015, 12, 30)
OrderReport.for(begins, ends)
```

This will produce an SQL query that will look like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM 
  order_reports
WHERE
  order_reports.event_at BETWEEN '2015-12-12' AND '2015-12-30'
```

This way you leave Arel to deal with query building and you don't have to worry about SQL adapter combatibility.